# Find which views (if any) a field is used in (using dependencies?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have come across [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345449%28SQL.90%29.aspx) detailing how dependencies work and I was wondering if it would be possible to use these to see which views (if any) a field is contained within.

I've come across topics such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584107/sql-server-2005-search-views-for-certain-database-objects) which show how to find which entities are used within views, but I was hoping to be able to drill down a bit further and instead find out if a field is linked to any views? (Using Sql server 2005)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question

> ...find out if a field is linked to any views?

one could use the system view VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE in your database.  I created this view

```
USE [ScratchPad]
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT     second
FROM         dbo.deleteme
GO
```

Using the query below:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [VIEW_CATALOG]
      ,[VIEW_SCHEMA]
      ,[VIEW_NAME]
      ,[TABLE_CATALOG]
      ,[TABLE_SCHEMA]
      ,[TABLE_NAME]
      ,[COLUMN_NAME]
  FROM [ScratchPad].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE]
```

I recieved this result which includes the column and table name

```
## VIEW_CATALOG VIEW_SCHEMA VIEW_NAME   TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME
ScratchPad       dbo                      View_1     ScratchPad dbo          deleteme   second
```

Add a WHERE clause to the query and you should get your answer.

If you wish to look at constraints use the view "[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE]"

My system is MSSS 2K8 your 2K5 system should have the same system views

Comment: DO you know if there is an easy way to add 2 extra columns onto this script to tell you which field / entity is linked to that in column [table_name] and [column_name]? - rather than having to open up the view and look at it that way? Thanks :)

Comment: Davin did you scroll over in the second code block?  The results include the table name and column name

Comment: I did - sorry if wasn't clear - is it possible to include columns telling you which table / column is used in the related view? (i.e. for column 'second' for table 'deleteme' , what corresponding table and column in view_1 are used - so that I don't have to delve into each view to see how it is linked to the table?

Comment: I still do not understand your comment, sorry.  The view view_1 is a view on one column only named 'second' in the table 'deleteme'.

Answer (score 1):

Red Gate Software's [SQL Prompt 5](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) has a **Column Dependencies** feature that might be useful in this situation.  You hover over a column name in a script, and up pops a window containing a list of objects that use that column, including views.

You can download a 14-day trial for free, to see if this feature works for you.

Paul Stephenson
SQL Prompt Project Manager
Red Gate Software

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this (free) tool: 
http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/schemasurf/default.aspx

which (quote):

> Atlantis Schema Surf is our SQL
>   dependency & live entity ER diagram
>   tool - it is a free animated graphing
>   tool which allows you to easily
>   visualize the dependencies between the
>   objects in your SQL Server databases
>   in a live entity ER diagram.

Awesome tool.