# SQL Studio 2008 r2 - Copy Wizard (MO Method) Invalid column name (what object?)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Hi I am using the copy wizard in studio 2008 r2.

I am using the Management Objects method, as I cannot take the database offline.

The copy fails with the follwing error :

> Event Name: OnError  Message: ERROR : errorCode=0
>   description=Invalid column name 'Organisation'. helpFile=
>   helpContext=0
>   idofInterfaceWithError={C81DFC5A-3B22-4DA3-BD3B-10BF861A7F9C}
>   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dts.DtsTransferProvider.ExecuteTransfer()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()
>   Operator: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  Source Name: CDW_SQL_SQL_5  Source ID:
>   {8EF4C2A1-3B69-4729-8569-091F9B4863CB}  Execution ID:
>   {61878ECA-D8C4-441A-9988-53ECC75D9283}  Start Time: 25/09/2012
>   15:53:34  End Time: 25/09/2012 15:53:34  Data Code: 0

However it does not tell me what object the Column is on.  What is the most reasonable way for me to locate this column based on the error output?

Comment: How many tables do you have with the column `Organisation` in them?

Comment: Just found the following which will help me find that answer. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/  Is this more likely to be a constraint as a table surely cant have an invalid column name?  It either has it or is doesnt.  Or am  wrong?

Comment: Only 3 tables,  not such a terrible task!

Comment: Rethinking my first comment could a View be a contender?

Comment: Possibly, if they are indexed.

Comment: Very useful post for me.  Find columns used by Views:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244962/find-which-views-if-any-a-field-is-used-in-using-dependencies

Comment: I have 3 tables and 2 views containing the column - all can be selected, designed,  and contraints either dont exist or check ok.  :(