# Need to identify a table in all objects in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sysobjects

I need to identify a table that is mentioned anywhere in database (in stored proc, views, and, etc.).  I tried to find a query online, but couldn't find it.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Not sure why your question got downvoted. It seems to me to totally on topic and something that people need to find now and then.

Comment: You might find a query-based solution [here ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584107/sql-server-2005-search-views-for-certain-database-objects)

Comment: Or [here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/06/a-handy-search-procedure.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use this snippet when I'm looking for dependencies. In this case, you would replace the text with what you're searching (assuming you're on MS SQL Server):

```
USE [DBNAME]

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
FROM syscomments
WHERE [text] LIKE '%enter_search_here%'
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
```

You can also look for specific object types by adding a check for object property:

```
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1
```

Here is a [LIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx) of useful object properties!

Comment: Two problems with `syscomments`: (1) it's a backward-compatibility view that has been deprecated and should not be used (use `sys.sql_modules` instead), and (2) it breaks procedures > 4000 characters across multiple rows, so there is a chance it could miss procedures because your search term fell on the boundary. [See this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/06/a-handy-search-procedure.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I use the free SQL Search plugin for MS Management Studio for things like that: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/